# Is there a task manager equivalent that shows GPU usage history?

Tags: gpu

Is there an application which can show me GPU usage history in the same way as I can bring up task manager to see CPU usage? I would like to be able to see how much load I am putting on the GPU with my WPF applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) GPU-Z

2) RivaTuner

3) AMD Catalyst, Overdrive tab.

They all work with AMD cards, not sure about NVidia.

Comment: GPU-Z works with with NVidia

Answer (score 1):

AMD System Monitor is pretty good.  It gives you CPU and GPU % usage.